# Create Hive table to load logs in S3 subfolders

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to load log files in my S3 bucket to an Hive table but this logs are in different sub folders within my S3 bucket (abc-def/PMTA/2013/xxx,yyy,zzz sub folder). I am using the following hive command but it does not load any data to it:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE pmtalograw(
                                 type STRING,
                                 timeLogged STRING,
                                 timeQueued STRING,

ROW FORMAT delimited fields terminated by ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE

LOCATION 's3://abc-def/PMTA/2013';
```

Comment: To workaround this, I needed to specify the log folder

Answer (score 0):

Create an HIVE's table and loading content of PMTA log to the table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE pmtalograw(
type STRING,
timeLogged STRING,
timeQueued STRING,
timeImprinted STRING,
origin STRING,
recipient STRING,
orcpt STRING,
dsnAction STRING,
dsnStatus STRING,
dsnDiag STRING,
dsnMta STRING,
bounceCat STRING,
srcType STRING,
srcMta STRING,
dlvType STRING,
dlvSourceIp STRING,
dlvDestinationIp STRING,
dlvEsmtpAvailable STRING,
dlvSize STRING,
vmta STRING,
jobId STRING,
envId STRING)
ROW FORMAT delimited fields terminated by ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE

LOCATION 's3://abc-def/PMTA/Logs';
```

Comment: Simple Select statements to query the datas in hive table:

1. Find records where dsnstatus column is not equals to 'success' and filter required columns:

select timelogged, origin, dlvdestinationip from pmtalograw
where dsnstatus NOT LIKE '%success%';